# Best way to do math arithmetic (1 hour ago), and Date/DateTime based queries (created in the last day/minute/etc)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

```
{{year,month,day},{hour,minute,second}} = Ecto.DateTime.utc 
|> Ecto.DateTime.to_erl

hour_ago = {{year,month,day},{hour-1,minute,second}}
|> Ecto.DateTime.from_erl
```

This will give the time an hour ago, then I can use `where: x.inserted_at >= ^hour_ago`

Is there an easier or better way to do DateTime arithmetic and/or to query by date? How would I do a date range?

Comment: Have a look at the Timex library by Bitwalker at GitHub

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply use something like this:

```
from p in Post, 
  where: p.inserted_at >= datetime_add(p.inserted_at, -1, "hour")
```

The full info on the API you can find [here](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html)

Comment: This works for the query, but if I have a model and I want to see if it was created less than 1 hour ago, Ecto.Query.API.datetime_add from outside a query. It gives me an error.  ```the functions in Ecto.Query.API should not be invoked directly, they serve for documentation purposes only```

Comment: @PeterR Timex it is then :)

Comment: Timex does not appear to do arithmetic. @JustMichael